# Java MulticastSocket setSoTimeout freezes program

Tags: java, multicastsocket

I am trying to use multicastsockets in a program of mine. Today, I'm not sure what changed, but my program (which hasn't changed and was working fine before) started freezing on random occasion when the `setSoTimeout(int)` method was called. It's not consistently, the method may be called a few times before this happens. Any clues as to what this is?

Code:

```
private String[] getPlayerInfo() {
    sendMessageToPlayers("count", 500);
    String[] temp = new String[4];
    while (true) {
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
            DatagramPacket datagram = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            cSocket.receive(datagram);
            String message = new String(datagram.getData());
            if (message.contains("received")) {
                message.substring(message.indexOf("received") - 1, 1);
                int playerNum = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(message.indexOf("received") - 1, 1));
                temp[playerNum] = message.substring(message.indexOf("received") + "received ".length());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                cSocket.setSoTimeout(100000);
            } catch (SocketException e1) {
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

public void sendMessageToPlayers(String message, int timeout) {
    byte[] buf = (message).getBytes();
    DatagramPacket dg = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, group, 6789);
    try {
        cSocket.send(dg);
        cSocket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [setSoTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)) is

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds.
>   With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the
>   InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this
>   amount of time. If the timeout expires, a
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still
>   valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking
>   operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero
>   is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

And [SO_TIMEOUT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_TIMEOUT)

> Set a timeout on blocking Socket operations:
>
> - ServerSocket.accept()
> - SocketInputStream.read()
> - DatagramSocket.receive()
>
> The option must be set prior to entering a blocking operation to take
>   effect. If the timeout expires and the operation would continue to
>   block, java.io.InterruptedIOException is raised. The Socket is not
>   closed in this case.

I don't understand the usage you made of it.